# time series resampling with ruby

Tags: ruby, math, time-series

I'm looking for a ruby library that can convert an irregular time series to a regular timeseries through interpolation and resampling. I could write one myself but if there is a gem out there that can do this then I'll use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a library in Ruby, but there's gretl (find it at sourceforge) and the FFI gem (find it at github). This two libraries together will do the job, without rewriting the whole stuff. But if you plan to write a ruby library, that would be a great idea!